# converting php array into a single JSON object

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue with how I am converting my php array into a JSON object. No matter what I try, I either print everything out as multiple objects or it comes out as null.Wrapping it in `pre tags`, here is the closest that I got it:

My code:

```
$content = mysqli_query($dbcon, 
  "SELECT title, last_name AS lastname
   FROM revision, field_last_name
   WHERE vid = entity_id;"
);

echo "<pre>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($content))
{
  print json_encode($row);
  print '<br/>';
}
echo "</pre>";
```

My output:

```
{"0":"John Apple","title":"John Apple","1":"Apple","lastname":"Apple"}
{"0":"Kumar Patel","title":"Kumar Patel","1":"Patel","lastname":"Patel"}
{"0":"Michaela Quinn","title":"Michaela Quinn","1":"Quinn","lastname":"Quinn"}
{"0":"Peyton Manning","title":"Peyton Manning, MD","1":"Manning","lastname":"Manning"}
{"0":"John Doe","title":"John Doe","1":"Doe","lastname":"Doe"}
{"0":"Jane Lee","title":"Jane Lee","1":"Lee","lastname":"Lee"}
{"0":"Dan McMan","title":"Dan McMan","1":"McMan","lastname":"McMan"}
{"0":"Yu Win","title":"Yu Win","1":"Win","lastname":"Win"}
```

My two questions are:

1) Why is there a `"0":"John Apple"` and a `"1":"Apple"` when all I want is `"title":"John Apple"` and `"lastname":"Apple"` in my object?

2) Why is everything displaying as multiple objects?

Thanks!

**---EDIT---**

$arr = array()

```
echo "<pre>";   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($content))
{     
  $arr[] = $row;
}

print $arr;
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Because you are calling it in a while loop, it will json_encode every row.

Comment: field_last_name is your table name? can you distinguish each column name prefix by table name like revision.title in your query and get all data in a single array and then  json_encode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

field_last_name is your table name? can you distinguish each column name prefix by table name like revision.title in your query and get all data in a single array and then json_encode it?

```
   $content = mysqli_query($dbcon, 
      "SELECT title, last_name AS lastname
       FROM revision, field_last_name
       WHERE vid = entity_id;"
    );
    $arr = array();

    echo "<pre>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($content))
    {
      $arr[] = $row;
    }
      print_r(json_encode($arr));


    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I have looked into what you had said and adding the table name in front of the column name does not change my results. Using the while loop you have provided has just resulted in a blank white screen for me please see the edit I made above

Comment: can you print_r($row) in while loop? and let me know what you have got?

Comment: That seemed to have did it, but I do not understand what you changed to make it work? Could you please explain?

Comment: @scapegoat17: it was firstly done. we should use print_r or var_dump to print array for this reason you did not see your results. You printed array by print. if it worked then accept it :)

Comment: Haha, I will accept it, but I still don't understand how doing what you did answered the first question that I had. Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: I have get all data in an array one by one and then json_encode it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($content))
{
  print json_encode($row);
  print '<br/>';
}
```

To this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($content);
json_encode($row);
```

Comment: This would only print out one row and stop, not all rows in a single array object.

Answer (score 0):

...because you're printing out multiple objects.  If you want a single object which is an array, you need to append the results of `mysql_fetch_assoc` (see other answer covering field names vs positions) to an array, then `json_encode` the array in one shot.  Example:

```
$myarray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($content))
{
  $myarray[] = $row;
  print '<br/>';
}
print json_encode($myarray);
```

Comment: changing the to `mysql_fetch_assoc` has resulting in just displaying a blank white screen for me. Please see the edit to my questions that I made above.

Comment: Any time you get a blank screen, check your error_log.  A blank screen means the script died.  Assuming your edit is verbatim, you're missing a semicolon.